# Who is the person sitting to the left of corporal Hitler?

Tags: world-war-one, hitler, photography

My son, in my opinion, looks like the person sitting next to corporal Hitler in this photograph.

Does anyone know who this is or any information about where the photo was taken?
[image]

Comment: Now that is a very interesting question! And I also find the similarity between them.

Comment: Given all the green foliage behind your son, I'd say it was probably taken in a city park somewhere in a temperate climate. Most likely it was about an hour before sundown. ;-)

Comment: FYI -- related discussion on [meta](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com): *[Historic image puzzles](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/467/historic-image-puzzles])*

Comment: @T.E.D. You're right, the picture was taken in a city park.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's the exact description of the photo, according to [Hitlerpages.com](http://www.hitlerpages.com/JUNE26.html):

> Hitler and his fellow-soldiers in Fournes en Weppes, April 1915.
>
> First row: Adolf Hitler, Balthasar Brandmayer, Anton Bachmann, Foxl,
>   Max Mund. Second row: Ernst Schmidt, Johann Sperl, Jakob Weiß, Karl
>   Tiefenböck.

This way, your man is called [Balthasar Brandmayer](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balthasar_Brandmayer). But it turns out that he's not just "some random soldier sitting next to Hitler" as we could think.

In fact, he's an author of a book called "Two messengers" which was released in 1932. It speaks about the times of his war service and frequently refers to Hitler. I don't know if it was translated into English, but...

I recommend you the linked book "[Corporal Hitler and the Great War 1914-1918, The List Regiment](http://books.google.pl/books?id=9WdTxOQjqvcC&printsec=frontcover&hl=pl#v=onepage&q&f=false)" by John F. Williams, as there's a lot about Brandmayer, with quotes from his memoirs. Unfortunately many important pages are not included in the online preview, but there's still a lot to read about him.

Below there's another photo from the same session, with Brandmayer lying at the grass.

[image]

If any of you wonder, the dog's name is Foxl (Fochsl).

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks so much. My internet search for the answer earlier yielded nothing. I was overjoyed to see such a detailed and well-documented answer.

Here's the back story to how I found the picture. My son's friend in high school saw the picture in one of his classes and though the soldier setting next to Hitler in WW I looked a lot like him. My son showed the picture to family and we all agreed. Since there is some German heritage in him, we thought there might be some relation.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help. :)

Comment: Let me know please, if you actually find any relation between them. :)

Comment: @DougDomeny I'd argue it's a fairly common type e.g. in the Alpine regions of Germany, Austria, and Italy: for instance, [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5n5XB.png) could also be a relative of your son as pictured :)

Comment: @Drux, agreed, it was unlikely, but an interesting find.

Comment: @DarekWędrychowski, your English is very good. Are you familiar with Graceland (www.gracelandministries.com) in Krakow? They teach English. I had the opportunity to meet the women who teach when they were in the U.S. I'm on LinkedIn, Facebook and some other social sites if you wish to discuss more.